# I've downloaded minecraft forge but it is not downloaded [EDIT]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I've recently downloaded Minecraft forge on my windows 10 operating system (not windows 10 edition Minecraft) I downloaded forge 1.7.2, but there was no Forge profile so I made my own in the suitable version. I now understand that that was a bad idea because it is NOT Minecraft forge. I can tell from the lack of the logo, forge version text and 'mods' folder. I made my own 'mods' folder and extracted the littleblocks.jar file (the mod I was downloading at the time) into it and ran Minecraft. Nothing. I hope someone can provide an explanation for the absence of Forge on my workstation.

EDIT:I seem to have fixed forge a fit. The actual profile is now there but when I lay it does nothing. The launcher loads, disappears and then there's nothing. Please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you...

- Downloaded the correct version of Forge for Minecraft 1.7.2? The correct version is 10.12.2.11xx (xx can be any number, but it's probably 21, 47, or 61)
- Downloaded the "installer" version? The filename should be something like `forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.11xx-installer.jar`
- Correctly installed Forge? Make sure Minecraft and the launcher aren't running, and double-click the installer. The installer should create the "Forge" profile for you.

Also, if you didn't download Forge from [the official Forge website](https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.2.html), you might very well have downloaded a virus. Delete it immediately.

Answer (score -2):

If you got it from a website that wasnt minecraftforge.net Download Minecraft Forge from here!
[[Clicky here!]](https://files.minecraftforge.net/#Downloads)

If you did download Minecraft Forge from minecraftforge.net, I dont know what the hell is happening

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the OP's question. He said that he has already downloaded Forge.